# Custom data formatting and pattern matching

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, text-processing, pattern-matching

I am trying to format custom data using pattern match. I am not getting expected format. Though I am not shell script savvy but I was able to build a script based on references from multiple sources here from SE.

Need help with some suggestions, please advise.

Input data:

```
WWWW PPPA TTTT
XX XY
XA XB
XB XC
XY XE
HHHH PPPA 400 XXX6
WWWW PPPB TTTT
XB XC
XY XE
HHHH PPPB 200 XXX1
WWWW PPPC TTTT
XX XY
XA XB
XB XC
HHHH PPPC 300 XXX9
WWWW PPPA TTTT
XA XB
XB XC
XN XX
HHHH PPPA 300 XXX6
WWWW PPPD TTTT
XX XY
XA XB
XB XC
XY XE
XN XA
HHHH PPPD 500 XXX4
```

Expected Output:

```
WWWW PPPB TTTT 
XX XC
XY XE
HHHH PPPB 200 XXX1
WWWW PPPC TTTT
XX XY
XA XB
XB XC  
HHHH PPPC 300 XXX9
WWWW PPPA TTTT
XA XB
XB XC
XN XX
XX XY
XA XB
XB XC
XY XE
HHHH PPPA 700 XXX6
WWWW PPPD TTTT
XX XY
XA XB
XB XC
XY XE
XN XA
HHHH PPPD 500 XXX4
```

Please see comments here, again this was built by referencing other codes. I myself am trying to understand the logic here. I am basic with shell and looking for learning and understanding more.

```
pattern='PPPA'

awk -v ptn="${pattern}" '                            # pass pattern in as awk variable "ptn"
$0 ~ "^WWWW "ptn"$" { save=1 ; next }                # start of group => set save flag; skip to next line
$0 ~ "^HHHH "ptn" " { save=0 ; next }                # end of group => clear save flag; skip to next line
save                { ++i ; line[i]=$0 ; next }      # if save=1 then store current line in next position of array line[]; skip to next line
                    { print }                        # otherwise print all other lines to stdout

END { if ( i >= 1 )                                  # if we found any matches ...
         { printf "%-561s%s", "WWWW", ptn            # print the new "WWWW" line
           for ( j=1 ; j<=i ; j++ )                  # then loop through our list of indices ...
               { print line[j] }                     # printing the associated line[] element
           fmt="HHHH %s %02i\n"                      
           printf "%-69s%-491s%02i" "HHHH", i, ptn   # print the "HHHH" line
         }
     }
' TESTX1.txt
```

What I am trying to achieve here is to combine 2 data sets with matching pattern. Search for `WWWW` pattern first, then search for `PPPA` pattern if matched. Then club the start and end records of this particular data block.

In the input data set you see there are 2 groups with `WWWW` and `PPPA` pattern. I want to combine them as one data group, while doing so also adjust the end record data count:

```
  HHHH PPPA 400 XXX6 
+ HHHH PPPA 300 XXX6 
= HHHH PPPA 700 XXX6  (400 + 300 = 700)
```

`WWWW PPPA TTTT` will remain same as they are identical for both data groups.

Script Output is not as expected:

```
WWWW PPPA TTTT
XX XY
XA XB
XB XC
XY XE
WWWW PPPB TTTT
XB XC
XY XE
HHHH PPPB 200 XXX1
WWWW PPPC TTTT
XX XY
XA XB
XB XC
HHHH PPPC 300 XXX9
WWWW PPPA TTTT
XA XB
XB XC
XN XX
WWWW PPPD TTTT
XX XY
XA XB
XB XC
XY XE
XN XA
HHHH PPPD 500 XXX4
```

Thank you for the solution, posting the actual data for which data is not manipulating. Logic stays the same but format is different.

Actual Data Input

```
WWW                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             PPPA                                                  TTTT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            XXXAAXX                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
XX XY
XA XB
XB XC
XY XE
HHH                                                                  500                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        PPPA                                                   TTTT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
WWW                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             PPPB                                                  TTTT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            XXXAAXX                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
XB XC
XY XE
HHH                                                                 3500                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        PPPB                                                   TTTT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
WWW                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             PPPA                                                  TTTT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            XXXAAXX                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
XA XB
XB XC
XN XX
HHH                                                                 1000                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        PPPA                                                   TTTT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
WWW                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             PPPC                                                  TTTT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         XXXAABB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
XX XY
XA XB
XB XC
XY XE
XN XA
HHH                                                                 4000                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        PPPC                                                   TTTT
```

Actual data expected output #

```
WWW                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             PPPB                                                  TTTT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            XXXAAXX                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
XB XC
XY XE
HHH                                                                 3500                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        PPPB                                                   TTTT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
WWW                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             PPPA                                                  TTTT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            XXXAAXX                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
XX XY
XA XB
XB XC
XY XE
XA XB
XB XC
XN XX
HHH                                                                 1500                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        PPPA                                                   TTTT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
WWW                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             PPPC                                                  TTTT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         XXXAABB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
XX XY
XA XB
XB XC
XY XE
XN XA
HHH                                                                 4000                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        PPPC                                                   TTTT
```

Comment: please see below I posted

Comment: what i am trying to achieve here is to combine 2 data sets with matching pattern. 
Search for WWWW pattern first, then search for PPPA pattern if matched then club the START and END  records of this particular data block. In the INPUT data set you see there are 2 groups with WWWW and PPPA pattern. I want to combine them as one data group , while doing so also adjust the END record data count. 

`HHHH PPPA 400 XXX6 + HHHH PPPA 300 XXX6 = HHHH PPPA 700 XXX6`
`400 + 300 = 700`
`WWWW PPPA TTTT will remain same as they are identical for both data groups`

Comment: added and deleted, please check now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to match the end of line `$` in your start pattern, but there is none at this position in your input.
Also the `END` block formatting of the header/footer is broken.

Slightly modified code:

```
pattern='PPPA'
awk -v ptn="$pattern" '
  $0 ~ "^WWWW " ptn " "{ save=1; header=$0; next }
  save && $0 ~ "^HHHH " ptn " "{ save=0; footer=$0; sum+=$3; next }
  save{ line[i++]=$0; next }
  1  # print current record
  
  END{
    if (i){
      print header
      for (j=0;j<i;j++) print line[j]
      $0=footer  # assign footer to current record
      $3=sum     # replace 3rd field with sum
      print      # print footer
    }
  }
' file
```

Output:

```
WWWW PPPB TTTT
XB XC
XY XE
HHHH PPPB 200 XXX1
WWWW PPPC TTTT
XX XY
XA XB
XB XC
HHHH PPPC 300 XXX9
WWWW PPPD TTTT
XX XY
XA XB
XB XC
XY XE
XN XA
HHHH PPPD 500 XXX4
WWWW PPPA TTTT
XA XB
XB XC
XY XE
XA XB
XB XC
XN XX
HHHH PPPA 700 XXX6
```

---

Modified code for the actual data with the following changes:

- match `WWW` and `HHH` as first field, the pattern as second (header) or third (footer) field
- save the old footer value in `oldvalue`, used to replace this value with `sum` in the `END` block
- use the second field for the footer value (`sum`, `oldvalue`)

```
pattern='PPPA'
awk -v ptn="$pattern" '
  $1=="WWW" && $2==ptn{ save=1; header=$0; next }
  save && $1=="HHH" && $3==ptn{ save=0; oldvalue=$2; sum+=$2; footer=$0; next }
  save{ line[i++]=$0; next }
  1
  
  END{
    if (i){
      print header
      for (j=0;j<i;j++) print line[j]
      sub(oldvalue, sum, footer) # replace oldvalue with sum
      print footer
    }
  }
' file
```

Output:

```
WWW                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             PPPB                                                  TTTT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            XXXAAXX                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
XB XC
XY XE
HHH                                                                 3500                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        PPPB                                                   TTTT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
WWW                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             PPPC                                                  TTTT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         XXXAABB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
XX XY
XA XB
XB XC
XY XE
XN XA
HHH                                                                 4000                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        PPPC                                                   TTTT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
WWW                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             PPPA                                                  TTTT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            XXXAAXX                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
XX XY
XA XB
XB XC
XY XE
XA XB
XB XC
XN XX
HHH                                                                 1500                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        PPPA                                                   TTTT
```

Comment: Thank you !  I It works fine but I see there is a data loss occurring as part of this. 

from this block `WWWW PPPA TTTT`

the following row with data `XX XY` is getting wiped out. Instead of appending 7 rows it is only appending 6 rows and removing 1 causing data discrepancy.

Comment: Oops, you're right. I used the wrong start index in the loop. Edited.

Comment: thank you. Can you please tell me how the logic for sum here is calculated ? 
Also I posted dummy data in the main question, I am trying to use the same script and logic for my actual data. It is not manipulating the data. The actual data format looks like Header format `WWWW<<557 spaces>>PPPA<<50 spaces>>TTTT`

Footer format `HHHH PPPA<<69 spaces>>TOTAL ROW COUNT with lenght of 4<<488 spaces>>XXX6` 

Can this be controlled by mentioning specific position point ? Please let me know if posting actual data can be helpful here. Thank you

Comment: Well, you should have posted an example with real data in the first place. The code adds the value of the third field to `sum` whenever a matching end block is found. Your two regexes won't match if you have multiple spaces between those fields. 
Try to change the conditions to `$1=="WWWW" && $2==ptn{ ... }` and `save && $1=="HHHH" && $2==ptn{ ... }` to match the first two fields instead.
And you will have to reformat the footer using `printf` to add additional spaces.

Comment: thank you Freddy for the details. I have updated the question with the actual data format. Please let me know where would I have to make code changes to handle the additional data spaces. Thank you again for your responses its a good learning for me.

Comment: See the update, the matched `PPPA` block is of course printed as the last block.

Comment: hey Freddy, thank you -- this script has been working fine but I noticed an issue just now in regards to FOOTER row. Format is staying intact for 2 PPPA blocks when FOOTER (HHH) with lower value is first and higher value is second. Format is changing for 2 PPPA blocks when FOOTER (HHH) with higher value is first and lower value is second. 

`in above example HHH 500 in first PPPA block, HHH 1000 second PPPA block format after conversion total  = 1500 is staying intact`

--CONTINUED in next comment--

Comment: `if there is higher value first HHH 1000 in first PPPA block,  HHH 500 in second  PPPA block the conversion total = 1500 gets shifted right by 1 extra space`

`using same example if i do 1000 + 50 = 1050 it gets shifted by 2 extra space`
Can you please let me know how can this be handled in your code for this scenario ? Please let me know if I show post my query with data sample in the main question.

Comment: Replace the substitution line with `sub(sprintf("%-" length(sum) "s", oldvalue), sum, footer)` which right-pads `oldvalue` with spaces to the length of `sum` in the replacement.

Comment: I have modified it and still noticing the formant issue, could you please check my reply below, I have posted it for easy reference.  Will delete it later after you refer it. Thank you.

Comment: Oh, I thought you were talking about the 3rd field `PPPA` shifting to the right and didn't notice the value itself also shifting to the right. Can you try the same as above, but remove the `-` in `sprintf("%-"` to add spaces to the left side? Will check tomorrow.

Comment: Freddy, thank you -- this fix worked.

Comment: hey Freddy, I am trying to extend the summing part for other fields as well,. In this example we are summing up field number 2 for PPPA block which is fine. For example lets say I have 4th field that I want to sum it up, I have written below code, but unable to understand how to format print statement in if block.

`save && $1=="TRL" && $3==ptn{ save=0; oldvalue=$2; sum+=$2; oldvalue1=$4; sum1+=$4; footer=$0; next }`

can you please advise how can it be formatted to add other summed up field values in if statement ?
 `sub(sprintf("%" length(sum) "s", oldvalue), sum, footer)`

Thank you

Comment: If you have multiple integer values per record you can't use `sub()` or you could end up replacing the wrong value if the old values of `$2` and `$4` are the same. You could assign the new values directly to the fields, i.e. `$2=sum; $4=sum1` and print the modified record using [printf](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Printf-Examples.html).
You will have to know the length of each field.